# Set View Controller Subview Loaded from Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom view controller I load from a Storyboard. When I try to set one of its subviews nothing happens (remains generic white view). What I don't understand is if I try to set VC.view it works fine. Why is this? Everything seems to be initialized after I load from the Storyboard. Where would I set the VS's subview?

Comment: What do you mean by "set one of its subviews"? Show the code you're using to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this slightly confusing behaviour is how it is 'supposed' to work.  When a view controller is loaded, its view is not - at least not until it is actually needed.  See [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html) for further info.  Only when the view controller is presented, will it then load the view.  As you have found, this is tiresome, because you often want to set some of the the subviews' properties **before** it is presented (say in a `prepareForSegue` or prior to `pushViewController:` or `presentViewController:`).

There is a work around - based on what you have observed.  If you directly access the view property, the view controller will immediately load the view and all its subviews.  So, if you want to set subview properties, just "touch" the view itself:

```
NSLog(@"View tag is %i", viewController.view.tag);
```

and you should then be able to access the subviews.

Alternatively, you could pass the relevant data in (non-UI) properties of your view controller, and then set up the subviews using that data during `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: I tried to pass the view I wanted to display to a temporary property on the view controller and then load it into the correct subview in viewDidLoad/viewWilLAppear and it still doesn't work. Currently, the only way I can display the view is to set it as the viewControllers view, not subview. Thanks for the response, any other ideas on what I might be doing incorrectly?

Comment: If you post some code, I'm sure someone will have some thoughts.  And perhaps explain a little more of what you are trying to achieve.